# How to open form 2nd time when it's closed & it should not open again when already opened

Tags: c#, .net

i doing window app using c#.net 2.0 and oracle 10g

i have a form name FORM1 with menustrip

from the menustrip of FORM1, i am opening another form FORM2 and closing the same FORM2 after using it
but if i click that for the second time it is not showing

i also added code that if user press the same menustrip button for the second time before closing the same FORM2 it should not open and bring the already opened FORM2 to focus

Edit::
First attempt -----------------

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    FORM2 f2 = Application.OpenForms["FORM2"] as FORM2 ; 
    if (f2 != null) 
    { 
        f2 .WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; 
        f2 .BringToFront(); 
        f2 .Activate(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        f2 = new FORM2(); 
        f2.Show(); 
    } 
}
```

Second Attempt --------------

```
private void FORM2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{ 
    this.Hide(); 
    e.Cancel = true; 
}
```

with this code i am able to open same FORM2 multiple times when the user clicks the menustrip multiple times.. i dont want that to happen

third attempt ------------

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    FORM f2 = new FORM2(); 
    f2.Show(); 
}
```

this code also doing the same as second attempt

fourth attempt --------------

```
private FORM2 f2 = null; 
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (f2 == null) 
    { 
        f2 = new FORM2(); 
    } 
    f2.Show(); 
    f2.Activate(); 
}
```

i have tried all the above coding but am not able to get what i am expecting.. can you people find out & help me what am i missing here..

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: as bansi points out, it will help us answer your question if you post your code for us to review

Comment: First attempt
-----------------

private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
FORM2 f2 = Application.OpenForms["FORM2"] as FORM2 ;
if (f2 != null)
{
f2 .WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
f2 .BringToFront();
f2 .Activate();
}
else
{
f2 = new FORM2();
f2.Show();
}
}

Comment: Second Attempt
--------------


private void FORM2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
this.Hide();
e.Cancel = true;
}


with this code i am able to open same FORM2 multiple times when the user clicks the menustrip multiple times.. i dont want to happen that

Comment: third attempt
------------

private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

FORM f2 = new FORM2();
f2.Show(); 
}

this code also doing the same as second attempt

Comment: fourth attempt
--------------

private FORM2 f2 = null;
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (f2 == null)
{
f2 = new FORM2();
}
f2.Show();
f2.Activate();
}




i have tried all the above coding but am not able to get what i am expecting.. 

can you people find out & help me what am i missing here..

Comment: Edit your Question with your code. Don't paste in comments...

Comment: I really don't understand what behavior you're expecting. The second attempt is what I would have posted as an answer, based on my understanding of your question title. Can you perhaps add more elaboration? And please use the [edit] link, not the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The Application.OpenForms collection is not reliable.  Form instances disappear from that collection without trace when you alter certain properties of the form, like the ShowInTaskbar property.  This is a well-known bug in Winforms, the possible reason you cannot get your original attempt to work.

The reliable alternative is to keep track of the life of the form instance yourself.  Like this:

```
    private Form Form2Instance;

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Form2Instance == null) {
            Form2Instance = new FORM2();
            Form2Instance.FormClosed += (s, ea) => Form2Instance = null;
        }
        Form2Instance.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        Form2Instance.Show();
        Form2Instance.BringToFront();
    }
```

Listening for the FormClosed event and setting the reference to null is the crucial part of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for ur time .. wil check & get back 2 u